# How to plot pinging results into a graph?

Tags: graphics, ping, raspberrypi

I need to find a way of plotting my pinging results into a graph for a project on my raspberrz PI. So
`ping 192.168.100.2` would display the replies and packet losses on a graph.

Answer (score 1):

I would use smokeping.

```
sudo apt-get install smokeping
```

Here's a great guide for configuring smokeping and accessing it on the web. I set mine up similarly, so it works. 
 http://linoxide.com/monitoring-2/setup-smokeping-latency-monitoring-ubuntu-15-04/
When configured, just set whatever ip address you like as your target. (your probe should probably be "fping" and your host is your server).

Comment: A little more explanation about how to use the suggested program would be nice :-)

Comment: you're right, will do